# How do I make a server automatically move files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files

I have a folder and I would like all the files that are put into that folder to instantly be moved to another folder. Is this possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your source directory is `aaa` and your target directory is `/path/to/bbb` this could satisfy your requirement:

```
rmdir aaa
ln -s /path/to/bbb aaa
```

Now anything put into `aaa` will instantly be present in `bbb`, because they are effectively the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky.

The easy way is to set up a looping job that moves the files if there are some. Make it pause at least one second between two iterations.

If minutes are ok a simple **cron** job will do.

If you need instant action look at **ionotify**.